# Current ratings for SAM7-P256 Olimex board

Tags: arm

I have bought an Olimex SAM7-P256 board. The power supply is given as 6V AC or DC. There is not max current ratings. I am seeing different current ratings for 6V power supply in market. Can anyone give me the current ratings for the board.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly a software related question and I think you're more likely to find an answer on http://chiphacker.com perhaps. (Or by asking Olimex directly, they've seemed quite responsive when I've asked them questions in the past)

Comment: thanks I asked them and got the reply that its ok to have any current rating as long as the voltage doesn't exceed 6V.